# Count Parent Document from a "view" in Xpages

Tags: javascript, xpages, domino-designer-eclipse

I have table row named "View All Topic" in which there is a computed field which indicates the total count of the document from a view named "topic".

This view is categorized view and don't have separate response form.

So now I was looking to get the total count of document from this view but,I only want to return the parent document count instead of both all the entries with response document(child document).

Total documents in the view is 6 in which 2 are the responses.So, except responses I want to retrieve the Parent Document count that is 4.

I found the solution with this javascript. But need to know if have any simpler solution for this.
Any suggestion would be really appreciated.

```
 <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var currentDb:NotesDatabase = session.getCurrentDatabase();
    var currentView:NotesView = currentDb.getView("topic");
    var docColl:NotesViewEntryCollection = currentView.getAllEntries();
    var c = docColl.getCount();
    var r =0;
    for(i=1;i<=c;i++){
    var en:NotesViewEntry = docColl.getNthEntry(i);
    var docs:NotesDocument = en.getDocument();
    if(!docs.isResponse())
    r++;
    }
    return r;}]]>
    </xp:this.value>
            <xp:this.converter>
                <xp:convertNumber type="number"></xp:convertNumber>
            </xp:this.converter>
         </xp:text>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm well there are probably several ways to go about this.. Respectfully your code is not one of them.  You should avoid "getNthEntry()" at all costs as it's a horrible performer.  If you did want to stick with you're solution you should get rid of the for loop and use something where you can do getNextEntry(entry) or a getNextDocument(doc).

The SIMPLEST method might be just updating the view if that's an option.  The Parent document has a form that's likely different then the response. So you could add a column to the effect of @if(@contains("form", "myParentForm");1;0)...  something like that.  so you return a 1 if it's a parent and 0 if not.  then you set the column to get the total and then use the NotesViewNavigator class to pull that number back.

If you didn't want to add a column.  Then again you're best solution will likely be with the NotesViewNavigator.  This should be VERY FAST.  you want to navigate to the first entry - which is likely a Parent.  Then you loop through doing getnextSibling to job over any response documents.  Should be a lot of examples around but here's one:
http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/lotusscript/lotusscript.nsf/1efb1287fc7c27388525642e0074f2b6/11c5837eb09e23a78525675300720a16?OpenDocument

I guess of course you could create a new hidden view that has the same selection formula minus the part that's picking up the responses.  If you had a view with only the parents then you could put all the documents or entries into a collection and then simply do collection.getCount()...  something like that.

Good Luck!

Comment: Definitely - avoid looping through documents! The best option is extra view column with totals and `@If( @IsResponseDoc; 0; 1 )` value. For hackers: `1 - @IsResponseDoc`